# iOS4 - swipe to change UIWebview url?

Tags: ios4, uiwebview, uiscrollview

Wondering on the best way to implement this - I want the effect the BBC News app has where you go to a story, then can swipe left or right to navigate to the next ones.

I'm thinking I could set up a UIScrollView in code depending on how many stories are in the queue (I'd limit it to a maximum of about 10 anyway) - is this the most logical way or should I be looking at gestures etc?  I presume there is some method to detect the swipe in the UIScrollView so I could load the next story just as it's being requested?

Any pointers or help on this one would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is OK to implement that way. In fact, I created some applications that use this approach, and it works pretty well.

Simply create an instance of an UIScrollView, set it to paginate calling `[scroll setPagingEnabled:YES]`, and implement the delegate method `-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` (remember that you must use the protocol *UIScrollViewDelegate*) to know when the page changes.

As of the web views, you create and add them to the scroll view as you would normally do.

To know at which scroll page you are at, you may want to use a code like this in the *scrollViewDidSCroll* method:

```
int page = (scroll.contentOffset.x / scroll.frame.width);
```

Then you can use an instance variable to hold the page the scroll it currently at, and the previous code to check if the user has scrolled enough to consider it as a new page.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I figured it was probably the best way but as this is my first app I don't want to fall into any dark holes which may cause memory issues etc.  I'm going to experiment with this a bit and hopefully learn a lot!